# Use Custom Control in FXML Document

Tags: java, javafx

How can I use a custom control in a FXML document? I know here are many answers about that, but all examples extends from existing controls like buttons, labels or even panels. But I extend from the 'Control' class and it don't work.

---

```
public class MyControl extends Control {
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import .MyControl?>

<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>

    <Pane fx:id="pane">
        <MyControl></MyControl>
    </Pane>
</Scene>
```

---

If I extend from any other control like a button or something, it works fine. What I need to do?

Comment: I found this: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm

Comment: This don't really help. If you look in the example codes, they extend from other existing controls. I'm writing a full control from scratch. On this page they use a VBox... | I used google before too. After hours of research I finally asked here.

Comment: Define *"Does not work"*. What does the exception say? Does fixing the import work (you probably should move the class to some package other than the default package anyways). If there is no exception, describe what's wrong. (I guess there is no visual result on screen...)

Comment: @CederikAlthaus Try this site http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/.       http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in JavaFX `Control` don't work like that, it always need a `Skin<C>` in order to render.
Try this:

```java
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class MyControl extends Control {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new SkinBase<MyControl>(this) {
            {
                Pane pane = new Pane();
                pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(getSkinnable().prefWidthProperty());
                pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(getSkinnable().prefHeightProperty());
                pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                getChildren().add(pane);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import MyControl?>

<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>

    <Pane fx:id="pane">
        <MyControl prefWidth="500" prefHeight="500"></MyControl>
    </Pane>
</Scene>
```

But this is just an example. You should explore better ways to create custom Controls, check for `createDefaultSkin()` in regular classes like `Button` and `Checkbox`.